Realizar una búsqueda y del resultado mostrar los registros anteriores y siguentes (mysql)
Supongamos que tengo la siguiente tabla
tabla_a
----------------
|id| articulo  |
|--|-----------|
|1 |caja       |
|2 |baul       |
|3 |cofre      |
|4 |cuchara    |
|5 |mesa       |
|6 |marco      |
|7 |sillon     |
|8 |taburete   |
|9 |silla      |
|10|closet     |
|11|base-cama  |
|12|colchon    |
|13|lampara    |
|14|ventana    |
|15|repisa     |
----------------

lo que busco es realizar una consulta por parte del usuario que dara un resultado
SELECT * FROM tabla_a WHERE articulo LIKE "mesa";

Del resultado de la consulta anterior quiero mostrar los 2 datos anteriores y siguientes a este que serian:
-cofre (dato anterior)
-cuchara (dato anterior)
-mesa (dato solicitado)
-marco (dato siguiente)
-sillon (dato siguiente)


Algo no aclarado por el autor de la pregunta es, que si es obligatorio hayan 5 registros, claro, a menos que el id encontrado esté en los extremos.
Menciono lo anterior porque si los id no son consecutivos, las consultas basadas en operadores matemáticos o rangos no traerán la cantidad solicitada.
La siguiente consulta trae los 2 valores menores al id y los 3 mayores o iguales al id, usando ORDER y LIMIT.
Al final todo está envuelto por otro SELECT para que el resultado quede ordenado por id.
SELECT * FROM (
    (SELECT * FROM tabla_a 
    WHERE id < (SELECT id FROM tabla_a WHERE articulo LIKE '%mesa%' LIMIT 1)
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2)
    UNION 
    (SELECT * FROM tabla_a 
    WHERE id >= (SELECT id FROM tabla_a WHERE articulo LIKE '%mesa%' LIMIT 1)
    ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 3)
) AS TEMP
ORDER BY id


puedes realizar esto por medio de un bloque anonimo, en el cual obtienes el ID del resultado de tu consulta y por medio de la sentencia UNION ALL unir los querys, acá un ejemplo.
DECLARE
    v_id int
BEGIN
    SELECT id INTO v_id FROM tabla_a WHERE articulo = 'mesa'

    SELECT * FROM tabla_a WHERE id IN(v_id-1, v_id-2)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM tabla_a WHERE articulo = 'mesa'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM tabla_a WHERE id IN(v_id+1, v_id+2)
END

Es importante recalcar que si usas la sentencia LIKE puedes obtener más de un resultado, por lo que lo ideal sería comparar con un valor exacto o bien, limitar la consulta para que solo obtengas un unico valor.

Tambien puedes usar BETWEEN

Si estas usando versiones posteriores a MySQL 8 puedes usar una cláusula WITH, enumerando filas para que obtengas los 2 artículos anteriores y los 2 siguientes al artículo que quieres buscar
SET @rn := 0;

WITH Articulos AS (
    SELECT *,
           (@rn := @rn + 1) AS rn
    FROM tabla_a
    ORDER BY id
)
SELECT articulo
FROM Articulos
WHERE rn BETWEEN (
        SELECT rn - 2
        FROM Articulos
        WHERE articulo = 'mesa'
    )
    AND (
        SELECT rn + 2
        FROM Articulos
        WHERE articulo = 'mesa'
    );

DEMO
Y si estas usando versiones más antiguas puedes usar subconsultas
SET @rn := 0;

SELECT articulo
FROM (
    SELECT id, articulo, (@rn := @rn + 1) AS rn
    FROM tabla_a
    ORDER BY id
) AS Articulos
WHERE rn BETWEEN (
        SELECT rn - 2
        FROM (
            SELECT id, articulo, (@rn2 := @rn2 + 1) AS rn
            FROM tabla_a, (SELECT @rn2 := 0) AS anterior
            ORDER BY id
        ) AS Tmp
        WHERE articulo = 'mesa'
    )
    AND (
        SELECT rn + 2
        FROM (
            SELECT id, articulo, (@rn2 := @rn2 + 1) AS rn
            FROM tabla_a, (SELECT @rn2 := 0) AS siguiente
            ORDER BY id
        ) AS Tmp
        WHERE articulo = 'mesa'
    );

DEMO
